# Top N in SSRS Reports

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I would like to be able to do a Top 20 locations filter on my SSRS report to show what locations are logging the most calls. I'm not sure how to use the Top N feature as it only seems to sow one line this way.

Comment: How are you getting the data into your dataset?

Comment: Assuming you're referring to SQL `SELECT TOP N...`, it's possible you just need to create a group in your report and group on the Id to show all of the records.

Comment: Hello,I am referring to the Select TOP N SQL.  I am getting my dataset from a shared dataset? I am not sure how you would group that?